# Multi column list in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlist, multiple-columns

First of all, I'm using Swing in Java. In my application, I need to have a multi column list (if that's what I should call it). What I mean by a multi column list is something like windows explorer's list view mode of showing files and folders.

So, all of the columns of my list are going to have the same object (files for instance), but I want to be able to put them on different columns, in order to have a wider view.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can do that?

Thanks,
Reza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may use:

```
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
```

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem! This typically works for me also.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). This will handle creating scroll bars and such for you, which would solve the issue of running out of vertical space, and thus eliminating the need for extra columns.

Comment: Please do not only link to resources but include them in the answer.